# Average value of $\ln(1+e^x)$ when $x$ is normally distributed

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Does the following integral admit a closed form answer:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm d x \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\nu}\right) \ln(1+e^x)$$

where $\nu>0$ and $\mu$ are finite real parameters. This is just the average value of $\ln(1+e^x)$, when $x$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\nu$ (forgetting the normalization constant).

I tried with symbolic processing software (Mathematica and WolframAlpha), and both return the input expression unevaluated, suggesting that a closed form solution does not exist, or at least it is not obvious.

Comment: Even the case $\mu=0,\nu=1$ looks hard. It can be wrriten as a series though:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\ln(1+e^x)dx=1-\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\exp\left(\frac{n^2}{2}\right)\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt 2}\right)$$

Comment: @Nyssa That's asymptotic only, right? Do you know if the error can be controlled?

Comment: For large $x$ you can just assume $ln(1+e^x) = x$ and the error can be controlled very well. For small $x$ you can use a talor expansion